# Random Hex generator (only grey colors)

Tags: javascript

I found on stackoverflow this color generator :

`Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0`

It works fine. The only problem is that I'd like to generate random colors, but only of different shades of grey.

I have no idea how I could achieve something like this.

Comment: Just generate a single random number between 0 and 255 and use that for the r,g and b component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var value = Math.random() * 0xFF | 0;
var grayscale = (value << 16) | (value << 8) | value;
var color = '#' + grayscale.toString(16);
```

`color` will be a random grayscale hex color value, appropriate for using in eg `element.style` properties.

Note: there are several ways to coerce the random floating-point number to an integer. Bitwise OR (`x | 0`) will usually be the fastest, as far as I know; the floor function (`Math.floor(x)`) is approximately the same speed, but only truncates for positive numbers (you'd have to use `Math.ceil(x)` for negative numbers). Bitwise operators won't work as expected for numbers that require more than 32 bits to represent, but `Math.random() * 0xFF` will always be in the range `[0,255)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use RGB, rgb grays can be created by supplying the same number in all three arguments i.e. rgb(255,255,255) (the number must be between 0 and 255).

```
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            min = Math.ceil(min);
            max = Math.floor(max);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; 
        }


        var randomNumberString = String(getRandomInt(0,255));
        var color = "rgb(" + randomNumberString + "," + randomNumberString + "," + randomNumberString + ")";
```